# Generate excel sheet using linq in asp.net core

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp.net-core

I need to generate excel sheet , with multiple tabs/worksheets from database using  LINQ.
I am using asp.net core.

Comment: Start here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) for .NET Core:
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

or you can use [NPOI for .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI).

But with Linq alone, you can't.

Alternatively, you can use [OpenMCDF](https://github.com/ironfede/openmcdf) to create a BIFF-format Excel file (*.xls)

Or you could use [CarlosAg's ExcelXmlWriter](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/) or you could create a CSV file, or the [OfficeOpenXmlSDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).